# Remove rows that exist in another pd.dataframe based on a few columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have df a and df b and I need to get df c if matchcolumns (color and value) exist in both a and b.

What I have so far:

```
c = a[a[matchcolumns] == b[matchcolumns]]

a
color value cost
red 0.1 5.99
blue 0.2 6.99
green 0.3 9.99

b
color value cost
red 0.1 0.9

c 
color value cost
blue 0.2 6.99
green 0.3 9.99
```

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: Hi the expected result is df c

Comment: your current `c` shows a disjoinment but not matching

Comment: @Roman from the title I believe OP wants to remove the common rows

Comment: @mozway, the title and the main sentence  (as well as expression) are in contradiction, so I elaborated

Comment: @Roman but you're right, the question has some ambiguities ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the below code gives you the results you are looking for

```
c = pd.merge(a, b, on=['color', 'value'], how='inner')
c.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an outer `merge` with indicator and remove the common rows:

```
cols = ['color', 'value']

c = (a.merge(b[cols], on=cols,
             how='outer', indicator=True)
      .loc[lambda d: d.pop('_merge').ne('both')]
     )
```

Or, if you have no duplicates in the two inputs:

```
c = (
 pd.concat([a, b])
   .drop_duplicates(subset=cols, keep=False)
)
```

Output:

```
   color  value  cost
1   blue    0.2  6.99
2  green    0.3  9.99
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
mrg_idx = pd.merge(a[['color', 'value']],b[['color', 'value']]).index

print( a.iloc[mrg_idx] )
```

```
  color  value  cost
0   red    0.1  5.99
```